# What is the symbol on the pauldron of the storm troopers who guard Grand Admiral Thrawn's office?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In Star Wars Rebels Season 3 Episode 17 ("Through Imperial Eyes"), the stormtroopers that guard Grand Admiral Thrawn's office on his Star Destroyer have a black pauldron on their right shoulder with a white symbol on it. It is also seen on the uniform of a few of his officers.

[image]

[image]

**What is it, what does it represent and why do only Thrawn's troopers wear it?**

Comment: I would assume it's a stylised Chimaera, given that Thrawn's ship is called the Chimaera and given his obsession with that creature....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It's a stylized Chimaera, which is the name of Thrawn's ship.**

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chimaera_(creature)

As a Grand Admiral, Thrawn was allowed to "brand himself," and as such his ship, stormtroopers, and some of his officers wore the symbol of a Chimaera.

Comment: You seem very certain, but is there anything you can offer as proof? For example, the logo in the link doesn't look like the arm badges.

Comment: I see absolutely no resemblance

Comment: It's a HEAVILY stylized version of the "eye stalks" on the full sized image (in between the long snakelike bits).  That full sized image is what's painted on the ship: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cx0KdgaVQAESVIe.jpg:large

Comment: I found some proof, so I’m writing another answer.

Answer (score 11):

### It’s a Chimera

The question was put to Lucasfilm Story Group leader Pablo Hidalgo in a recent episode of [*Rebels Recon*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ez3y6BZGrk&index=1&list=PL148kCvXk8pBBJ1-qxpc_fdnlg0WiFWDS):

> ANDI GUTIERREZ: I’ve got a question from Joshua Parish. He asks "Do the insignias Thrawn’s stormtroopers have on their pauldrons and uniforms have any significance?
>
> PABLO HIDALGO: They do. They are a stylized depiction of a chimera.
> Basically a three-headed monster. So that’s what those prongs
> represent. Basically anyone in Thrawn’s forces has the ability to wear that emblem.

As mentioned in another answer on this question, this is indeed the name of Thrawn’s ship, as mentioned in [another episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=netG0u3D2F0&list=PL148kCvXk8pBBJ1-qxpc_fdnlg0WiFWDS&index=5) of *Rebels Recon*:

> GUTIERREZ: So, Jake Anderson asks, “What was the artwork I spotted
> under Thrawn’s Star Destroyer in *Warhead*? Does it have any meaning?”
>
> HIDALGO: Uh…let me think about—yes! It is the *Chimera*; that’s
> the name of Thrawn’s ship, and so on the belly of the ship he’s got a
> stylized version of that creature.

Comment: Remind me never to come around your house for a seafood cocktail

Comment: @Valorum - I expect it was autocorrect.

Comment: Chuck another prong on the barbie

Answer (score 0):

That is the symbol of the **[7th Fleet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Seventh_Fleet)**, a fleet under the command of **Grand Admiral Thrawn**. The symbol there is to show loyalty to Thrawn and also to signify the fact that the trooper is conjoined with the 7th Fleet.